# Open closed principle for different filter conditions

Tags: c#, .net, open-closed-principle

The class ProductService, below, gets products based on different filters like by date, country, etc., from a database. ProductsService doesn't follow OCP, as adding new filter like getting products by Price requires changing the ProductsService code. How it can be fixed? Any suggestions/comments would be really helpful.

```
public class ProductsService : IProductsService
{
    public FilteredProducts GetProductsByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime EndDate) 
    {   
        //.....

    }
    public FilteredProducts GetProductsByCountry(string country)
    {
        //.....

    }

    public FilteredProducts GetProductsByCity(string city) 
    {
        //.....

    }

}

public class FilteredProducts
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products{set;get;}
    public int uniqueProducts { set; get; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public decimal Cost{set;get;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to represent each operation as separate class.

```
    public interface IProductFilter
    {
        FilteredProducts GetProducts(); 
    }

    public class GetProductsByDate : IProductFilter
    {
        private DateTime _startDate;
        private DateTime _endDate;

        public GetProductsByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime EndDate)
        {
            _startDate = startDate;
            _endDate = EndDate;
        }

        public FilteredProducts GetProducts()
        {
            // filter
        }
    }
```

You can then pass this implementation into your service, where it gets executed.

```
    public class ProductsService : IProductsService
    {
        public FilteredProducts FilterProducts(IProductFilter filter)
        {
            // execute the filter
            // return the products
        }
    }
```

You could even go as far as turning it into generic Command (for example [here](http://ayende.com/blog/154209/limit-your-abstractions-refactoring-toward-reduced-abstractions)) and executing all your database logic through it, ditching the "service" anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an Interface Called IFilter,which is responsible for FilterConstraints Contract.

```
public interface IFilter
    {
        void FilterConstraints(String FilterConstraints);
    }
```

Then i would have classes which are responsible for filtering and have those classes implement the IFilter Inetrface.

```
 public class FilterByCountry : IFilter
{
     public void FilterConstraints(string FilterConstraints)
     {
       //**Your Filter Constraints**/
     }
}

 public class FilterByCity : IFilter
{
     public void FilterConstraints(string FilterConstraints)
     {
         /**Your Filter Constraints **/
     }
}
```

This is the main class which has a constructor,that initializes IFilter(This is common among various FilterClassed)

```
public class ProductService
{
    private IFilter _filter=null;

    public ProductService( IFilter Filter)
    {
        _filter = Filter;
    }


    public void FilterProducts(String Constraints)
    {
         _filter.FilterConstraints(Constraints);
    }
}
```

So now if you want to call Filterbased on FilterByCountry,it would be like

```
var filterbycountry=new FilterByCountry();
var Filter=new ProductService(filterbycountry);
filter.FilterProducts("your constraints");
```

The Catch is if you want to add one more filter,you got have a new class and implement the IFilter to that filter class and have it invoked from product.That is your extending but not modifying the class,preserving open and closed principle

Comment: This would not really work if you have multiple filters, but just one service. And when your services are long-lived/singletons. Which is usually the case.

Answer (score -3):

Here the requirement is to add algorithm for each new filter without changing the service class. Strategy pattern fits to this requirement. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Actually, no, it is not useful. Please add more details to your description (how to do and not what to do) and include some code too as the original poster made the effort to do so.

Comment: I am sorry. My bad. User "restless" added the sample code for the mentioned pattern few minutes before.